# How do I map a network drive that requires a username and password in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I need to map a network drive from within a .NET application.  I'm going to need to use an AD Username and Password to authenticate.  Usually I just use a batch file with the `net use` command.  How do I do this from within C# or VB.NET code?

Comment: Why are you mapping a drive? To copy files?

Comment: @Ed B yeah, after thinking about it for a few more seconds, we're realizing we're going to approach this differently.

Comment: Ok..what I do is share a folder on the target machine..and do impersonation to save a file on another machine.  I can control the permissions of who writes to the folder, when setting up the share.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you looked at this?

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357

Also, you could just use net.exe via [`Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start) and pass it the parameters you've always used in the code below:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", "use K: \\\\Server\\URI\\path\\here");
```

This can also be used without a drive letter and then accessed through the UNC path.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", @"use @"\\Server\URI\path\here");
 System.IO.File.Copy(@"\\Server\URI\path\here\somefile.abc", destFile, true);
```

Comment: Hi, nice work, if you wrap it in a function you could go:

    `private void MapDrive(string driveLetter, string UNCPath)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
                "net.exe",  string.Format(@"use {0}: {1}", driveLetter)
        );
        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    }`

Comment: I wanted to throw in here that you can issue the net use command *without* a drive name then access the path via the UNC path.  This way you don't have to worry about what drives a user might have mapped already.

Comment: @Tim Coker The part about not using a drive letter is brilliant. Wish I knew that little gem years ago.

Comment: is it possible to get return values. e.g. access denied, or network unavailable. etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Heres some code that you should find to be a bit more reliable than just shelling out to the console.

```
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="driveLetter"></param>
''' <param name="uncName"></param>
''' <remarks>This was hand tested. We cannot automate because it messes with the OS</remarks>
 Sub MapDrive(ByVal driveLetter As Char, ByVal uncName As String)
    Dim driveLetterFixed = Char.ToLower(driveLetter)
    If driveLetterFixed < "a"c OrElse driveLetterFixed > "z"c Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("driveLetter")
    If uncName Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("uncName")
    If uncName = "" Then Throw New ArgumentException("uncName cannot be empty", "uncName")

    Dim fixedUncName As String = uncName
    'This won't work if the unc name ends with a \
    If fixedUncName.EndsWith("\") Then fixedUncName = fixedUncName.Substring(0, fixedUncName.Length - 1)

    Dim oNetWork As New IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshNetwork_Class
    Try 'This usually isn't necessary, but we can't detect when it is needed.
        oNetWork.RemoveNetworkDrive(driveLetter, True, True)
    Catch ex As Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        'Ignore errors, it just means it wasn't necessary
    End Try

    oNetWork.MapNetworkDrive(driveLetter, fixedUncName, True)
End Sub
```

http://clrextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55677#666894