# How to I copy a file from a computer that requires authentication to my local machine?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, authentication

When I use:

```
File.Copy(strRemoteFolder, strLocalFolder)
```

I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` with the following message: "Access to the path ... is denied."

In .NET, how do I copy a file from a remote computer that requires authentication to my local machine?  I understand that I'm going to need to supply a username and password in some fashion, but I don't know how to supply that information via an API in .NET.

Comment: Below you note that you've got differing domains and can't provide cross-domain credentials.  Do you have control over the remote PC?

Comment: @Tim we have control over the remote PC, but I believe for security reasons we aren't going to be able to create a policy that allows cross-domain access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unmanaged [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) function to get an account token for a session on the remote machine, and then call [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx) to use that session.  The MSDN page on [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx) describes how to make the p/invoke call to LogonUser.

You probably won't be able to use File.Copy since you won't have access to the local machine, but you can call [File.OpenRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx) to open the remote file and then revert your token.  Something like this:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

public static Stream OpenFileWithAccount(string filename, string username, string domain, string password)
{
    IntPtr token;
    if (!LogonUser(username, domain, password, 2, 0, out token))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }
    try
    {
        using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token))
        {
            return File.OpenRead(filename);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseHandle(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you got the arguments to the method call in the wrong order? ->(username, domain, password ....) as in the declaration

Comment: Where is wrong order? I can't find this. Help me. I got error when call LogUser method.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions to use `LogonUser` to login on the remote computer is definitively wrong. You should use `WNetAddConnection2` or `NetUseAdd` with parameter level 2 (`USE_INFO_2`) native API to make remote login.

Answer (score 0):

adjust the sharing privileges on the target system to allow access.

Comment: I specifically need a solution in .NET.  The target machine is on a different domain and we're unable to supply credentials across differing domains.

Comment: that does not invalidate the answer.  otherwise you could just write a program and get any protected data from any other machine.  not likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to copy files from a protected server without authenticating yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LogonUser()` contained within the advapi32.dll. I haven't used it personally, but it seems straight forward enough.

```
[DllImport("ADVAPI32.DLL")] 
public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, 
int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out int phToken);
```

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser

Answer (score 0):

Since you have control over both machines, you can create a local user on both machines with matching passwords, then run the program as that user.

Or you can just create the user on the remote machine and map a drive to that computer using the username/password of that user.  You would specify the user as `RemoteServer\NewUser`.  So you the parameters to net use as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198793/how-do-i-map-a-network-drive-that-requires-a-username-and-password-in-net/3198870#3198870) would be `use s: \\remoteserver\share /USER:RemoteServer\NewUser password`.  Then call net again but pass `use s: /delete` to clean up...

(The assumption here is that you've properly configured the user to have access to the specific share/folder in question.)