# Passing credentials when accessing remote server

Tags: c#, xml, remote-access

I'm trying to access a remote server to read an XML file, but I must log in the server first using username/password. I wrote this C# code to do this, but I'm still getting an exception (invalid username or password)

```
  XmlDocument Document = new XmlDocument();
string filePath = @"\\ServerIPAddress\C$\Temp\fileName.xml";
Document.Load(filePath);
```

I think the tricky part is to pass the username and password to the server. Any  ideas?

Comment: Is this a mapped drive on your network?

Comment: As for your edit: now it's a duplicate of [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share). Please show what you have tried, as this question is not unique. If you found anything that didn't work, do mention what you tried and what happened.

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3198793/745969

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use `NetworkCredential` for this. Check this [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

---

### Edit:

You may check this [MSDN Example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05f5c768-a31c-44b1-8fe2-d6a2aeec9c6f/how-to-remote-copy-) to copy file(s) over a network. You may use / modify this to read file(s) over the network.

Comment: I tried this before, but does not work:                                                            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ServerIPAddress");
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password", "WORKGROUP");