# C# saving a file path longer than 260 characters in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems

I have found some questions here asking the same thing, however the answers have not worked for me.  I have a path to another machine on the network where I store files in the following format;

```
\\machinename\share
```

We have paths longer than 260 characters. It does not allow me to save these paths when I use this code;

```
    private static void CreateDirectories(string totalPath)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(totalPath);

        if (file.Directory != null && !file.Directory.Exists)
            file.Directory.Create();
    }
```

I have tried using the following notations in the 'totalPath' parameter which don't work if I try to navigate to them in file explorer;

```
\\?\machinename\share
\\?\UNC\machinename\share
```

Am I using these paths correctly? Neither of these manage to navigate to the share in file explorer. Is there any other way I can save a file with a path that is longer than 260 characters using C# on windows?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: What is exactly the error message received?

Comment: As far as I remember, it's _file explorer_ that can't deal with paths longer than that. How are you verifying that the file is not written?

Comment: I would first try mapping a network drive. See [this](http://serverfault.com/a/654756) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3198870/6193089).